# How to set [<Out>] argument?

Tags: f#

I'm using out argument : `[<Out>] message : string`

But when I'm trying to set it : message <- "there is no figure on start position"

I'm getting error because message isn't mutable. How to set out argument ?

Comment: as a suggestion, not that you can't get the out parameter to work, but try to use a tuple instead to return all values you need from you function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expose method parameter with type `byref<string>` and attribute `[<Out>]` and use as argument a mutable value with address-of operator `&`:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

let mutable msg = "abc"

let outmsg ([<Out>]message : byref<string>) =
    message <- "xyz"

msg <- "test"
outmsg(&msg)
msg;;

val mutable msg : string = "xyz"
val outmsg : byref<string> -> unit
```

Answer (score 0):

Out parameters are like ref - you need to use `:=` like this (taken from MSDN docs)

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices;;
type dummy() =
     member this.MyMethod([<param: Out>] x : ref<int>) = x := 10 ;;
```